# Get a user visible text for the day of the week (correct language) using the day_of_week number from Java Calendar

Tags: java, android, format, locale, dayofweek

I've got a number representing the day of the week (directly originating from a constant `Calendar.MONDAY` for example). Now I'd like to get the user visible text of that day (using default locale of my mobile for the correct translation). I don't have a `Calendar` instance yet, just the number!

Currently I'm using code below, but I've got the feeling this should be easier, or at least without instantiating a complete `Calendar` (but I don't find a way to easily set the day_of_week to a Date).

```
private String LOCALE = Locale.getDefault();
private String FORMAT_DAY_OF_WEEK = "EEEE";

public convertDayOfWeekFromNumberToText(int dayOfWeekNumber) {
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(LOCALE);
  cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeekNumber);
  return new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT_DAY_OF_WEEK, LOCALE).format(cal.getTime());
}
```

Is this really the easiest way to retrieve the text? And is there a better solution if you'd like to get the best performance?

ps. in case Java7 and Java8 solutions are different, please provide both.

**Edit**

Thanks to John16384 @ comments I've found a better solution (see answer). I've converted the util-method described above to 2 different methods (1 for short and 1 for long format). Additional solutions would still be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Better solution I've found is this:

```
DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(LOCALE).getWeekdays()[dayOfWeek]
```

or depending on the format:

```
DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(LOCALE).getShortWeekdays()[dayOfWeek]
```

Not the ideal solution when working with a variable format, but it works for me for now (when using only 2 formats). Any additional advice would still be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

You can use a `DayOfWeek` and get the corresponding text in any locale:

```
int dayOfWeek = 1;
// get day of week from 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday)
DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.of(dayOfWeek);
// get value in specified locale
System.out.println(dow.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.getDefault()));
System.out.println(dow.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.getDefault()));
System.out.println(dow.getDisplayName(TextStyle.NARROW, Locale.getDefault()));
```

Assuming that the default locale is **English**, the output will be:

> Monday
>   Mon
>   M

You can change the code above to whatever `Locale` you need.

---

`Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` has values from 1 (Sunday) to 7 (Saturday), but the new API's `DayOfWeek` uses values from 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday). So to convert from one to another you need to adjust the values:

```
int d = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
// convert values for day of week
int dayOfWeek = (d - 1 == 0) ? 7 : d - 1;
// get day of week from 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday)
DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.of(dayOfWeek);
```